# What are the default programs to open docx, PDF and ZIP files on OS X?

Tags: macos, pdf, zip, file-extension, docx

I'm writing an article about DOCX, PDF and ZIP extensions. But first, I need to know the programs which are used to open these extension as default (without any third-party applications).

I don't have a Mac or any OS X based systems, so I can not complete my article. What applications open these kinds of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft .docx files, can be previewed using [*QuickLook*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look). To do that, just press <kbd>Space</kbd> after selecting such a file. They can be opened with [*TextEdit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit) since OS X 10.5 (thanks, Duvrai).

PDFs (and all kinds of images) are opened by [*Preview.app*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_%28Mac_OS%29). Many people prefer to use free and open-source [*Skim*](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) as a replacement PDF reader.

ZIP files and several other archive types are opened by [*Archive Utility*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_Utility) (previously called *BOMArchiveHelper* until OS X 10.5). [*The Unarchiver*](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver) is a well-known alternative to Archive Utility, which supports more file formats.

Comment: `docx` opens in TextEdit since at least OS X Lion (10.7).

Comment: Note that Archive Utility has almost no UI — the _only_ thing it does is unpack the contents of archives into a new folder. It cannot be used to modify an archive in-place (which I've often seen Windows users assume is normal functionality).